# How can I modify the response formatting itself?

Tags: yii2, response, formatter

In an action I need to responde with some XML. I use `Response::FORMAT_XML` for that, which works fine.

```
// In a controller:

public static function actionFetchData() {
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_XML;

    return [
        'a' => 'b',
        ['c', 'd'],
        'e' => ['f', 'g']
    ];
}
```

Result in Browser:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <a>b</a>
  <item>
    <item>c</item>
    <item>d</item>
  </item>
  <e>
    <item>f</item>
    <item>g</item>
  </e>
</response>
```

However, I'd like to change the root tags name from *response* to *data*. This should be possible since XmlResponseFormatter, which gets used to render the XML, has the property [rootTag](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-xmlresponseformatter.html#$rootTag-detail). How can I do that?

Or in general: How can I change the settings of a formatter (also JSON or whatever)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change format specific to particular action then use :.

```
 Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_XML;
 Yii::$app->response->formatters = [
        'xml' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\XmlResponseFormatter',
            'rootTag' => 'data',
        ],
    ];

    return [
        'a' => 'b',
        ['c', 'd'],
        'e' => ['f', 'g']
    ];
```

Comment: Small opimization: `Response::FORMAT_XML` could be used instead of `'xml'`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create an own formatter object for XML. Reason: In `Yii::$app->response` the formmatter is not present within the action - it will be created later, when the response gets rendered, what it too late to modify it. But we can create a new formatter and set it as the formatter for XML. This is a valid option.

```
public static function actionMetaInfo($docId) {
    $formatter = new XmlResponseFormatter([
        'rootTag' => 'data',
        'itemTag' => 'unnamed',
    ]);
    Yii::$app->response->formatters[Response::FORMAT_XML] = $formatter;
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_XML;

    return [
        'a' => 'b',
        ['c', 'd'],
        'e' => ['f', 'g']
    ];
}
```

Output now:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <a>b</a>
    <unnamed>
        <unnamed>c</unnamed>
        <unnamed>d</unnamed>
    </unnamed>
    <e>
        <unnamed>f</unnamed>
        <unnamed>g</unnamed>
    </e>
</data>
```

Here I changed the itemTag as well. This way, we can also modify other Formatter's properties (e.g. also in [JsonResponseFormatter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-jsonresponseformatter.html)).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify XML response formatter for all your application, you should simply add this to your configuration file :

```
'components' => [
    'response' => [
        'formatters' => [
            'xml' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\XmlResponseFormatter',
                'rootTag' => 'data',
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```